# Database record to Hash-of-hashes

Tags: perl

How can I generate a hash-of-hashes from a series of arrays? I need to go from this:

```
my @data = /one two three/;
my $value = 13:
```

to this:

```
$hoh = { 'one' => { 'two' => { 'three' => 13 } } };
```

This is used to transform the output of a database query to a hierarchical structure for visualization. Therefore the length of @data is fixed for all records, but varies from query to query.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you mean to initialize @data with the elements 'one', 'two' and 'three' above, then you can do something like this:
`my @data = qw/one two three/;
my $value = 13;`

my $hash = $value;
$hash = {pop @data => $hash} while @data;

What this does is initialize a variable with the final nested value, and then repeatedly build a hash pointing to that variable's content, using a key popped off the end of the data array.

Answer (score 5):

use [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Scalar-List-Utils/)'s reduce function to construct the hashref backwards, creating a hashref which becomes the value of the upper hashref, starting with the `$value` which remains a value, not a key.  This avoids the need for destructive operations like `pop`:

```
my $d = reduce { +{ $b => $a } } ($value, reverse @data);
```

You may need to suppress the `'Name "main::b" used only once: possible typo at '` warnings by enclosing the code in a block and turning off the `'once'` warning temporarily in that block with

```
no warnings 'once';
```

like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'reduce';
my @data = qw{one two three};
my $value = 13;

my $d = do {
  no warnings 'once';
  reduce { +{ $b => $a } } ($value, reverse @data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as perlish or compact as swestrup's but maybe easier to follow:

```
my @data  = qw/one two three/;
my $value = 13;
my %h     = ( );    # This is your final hash

my $deepest = undef;
my $hr      = \%h;
for my $x (@data) {
        $hr->{$x} = { };
        $deepest  = \$hr->{$x};
        $hr       = $hr->{$x};
}
$$deepest = $value;
```